# Installed module using requirements.txt but module not found when running app

Tags: python, python-3.6, folium

I have a `requirements.txt` which contains

```
folium==0.6.0
requests==2.20.0
```

I've created a virtualenv:

```
mkdir ~/virtualenvironment
cd virtualenvironment
```

here I have created a folder `myapp/` which contains my app.py and requirements.txt

```
virtualenv ~/virtualenvironment/myapp/
cd virtualenvironment/myapp/bin
source activate
pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt
```

I check with `pip3.6 list --local` (folium 0.6.0 is installed)

Now I run my app with `python3.6 app.py`

and I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import folium
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folium'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
It works when I perform `python3.6 -m pip install folium` but I want to use my requirements.txt. How can I do this?

Comment: i'm not sure if virtualenv also changes `pip3.6`. try to install it with just `pip`.
Edit (after reading your edit): pretty sure that's what happened. virtualenv changed `python3.6` but not `pip3.6`, so you actually installed the requirements to your system's python and then used the virtual python to run it.

Comment: @MCO thanks! That was it